# Show that these two field extensions are equal and find the minimal polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, roots, extension-field

The situation is the following: Let $f(x)= x^3-x+1\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$ and let $u$ be some root of $f$. Then define $b= -2u^2+u+1\in \mathbb{Q}(u)$. The claim is that $\mathbb{Q}(u) = \mathbb{Q}(b)$, and one should also find the minimal polynomial of $b$.

I was able to show the first part by looking at the degrees of the involved field extensions:

$$[\mathbb{Q}(u): \mathbb{Q}] = [\mathbb{Q}(u):\mathbb{Q}(b)] \cdot [\mathbb{Q}(b):\mathbb{Q}] $$

Then since $f$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}$, the degree of $\mathbb{Q}(u)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ cannot be one, and we know that it is smaller or equal to deg$f = 3$, so it must be $2$ or $3$. But these are both prime, so one of the degrees on the lhs must be equal to 1. Then one can show that the degree of $\mathbb{Q}(b)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ cannot be one explicitly by noting that if that were the case, then $b\in \mathbb{Q}$, so there is an $a\in\mathbb{Q}$ sucht that

$$2u^2 - u+a = 0 $$

i.e. $u$ would be a root of $g(x) = 2x^2-x+a$ and then finding a contradiction to $u\not\in \mathbb{Q}$.

The problem is that I have no idea how to calculate the minimal polynomial of $b$ now, since I have done the first part so abstractly that I have basically no information on $u$ or $b$. I've been sitting on this problem for days now, so any help would be appriciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a bit, umm, cheesy, but you may mimic this with matrices, beginning with a "companion" matrix for $u^3 - u + 1$   as square
$$
U = 
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
0&1&0\\
0&0&1\\
-1&1&0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
for which, well $U^3 - U + I = 0$

Part 2:
calculate $B = -2 U^2 + U + I.$  Which is all integers.
I get:
$$
B = 
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
1&1&-2\\
2&-1&1\\
-1&3&-1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

$$
B^2 = 
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
5&-6&1\\
-1&6&-6\\
6&-7&6 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Part 3:
Find the characteristic polynomial of $B,$   which is monic cubic with integer coefficients. If there are repeat roots the minimal polynomial of $B$  is allowed to have lower degree.

Either way, what is the minimal polynomial of the square matrix $B??$

Comment: So for the characteristic polynomial I get x^3+x^2-8x+11 which really does not have nice roots, but no repeated ones

Comment: @S.Farr  right. Let's see, now you want to solve for $ U =  pB^2 + q B + r I$    for, as we hope, rational $p,q,r.$   In any case  a linear system   which we hope is consistent.

Comment: How would that help us finding the minimal polynomial of $B$?

Comment: @S.Farr  you can do that separately using your $x^3 + x^2 - 8x + 11 $  which is the minimal polynomial for $B$  because it has no repeat roots. Meanwhile, I got my coefficients $p,q,r$  so that your two fields really are equal